# Testing with useEffect and jest.useFakeTimer()

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to create simple refresher component here

**Refresher.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Refresher = ({ onRefresh }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(onRefresh, 60000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [onRefresh]);

  return null;
};

export default Refresher;
```

However, when i try to test it using `jest.useFakeTimers()`, somehow it's didn't work. The stub is not called even after `jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()`

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Refresher from '../Refresher';

describe('Refresher', () => {
  test('should refresh the result every 60 seconds', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();

    const onRefreshSpy = jest.fn();

    const refresher = renderer.create(<Refresher onRefresh={onRefreshSpy} />);

    expect(onRefreshSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    refresher.update(); // Trying force update here

    expect(onRefreshSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

If not mistaken, the interval will not run if the component are not update, so i tried to use `refresher.update()`, but seems like it's not really work.

Anyone know how to fix the test here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to mock useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect. See issue [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/215)

```
describe('Refresher', () => {
  beforeAll(() => jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation(React.useLayoutEffect))
  test('should refresh the result every 60 seconds', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const onRefreshSpy = jest.fn();
    const refresher = renderer.create(<Refresher onRefresh={onRefreshSpy} />);
    expect(onRefreshSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    expect(onRefreshSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: oh great! this is very helpful, it's work with addtional `afterEach` clean up, but seems like it's not a very good way on testing `useEffect`, hopefully we will have a proper solution for that

Answer (score 0):

You have better control with the `modern` fake timers.

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Refresher from '../Refresher';

describe('Refresher', () => {
  test('should refresh the result every 60 seconds', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers('modern'); // default for Jest 27+

    const onRefreshSpy = jest.fn();

    const refresher = renderer.create(<Refresher onRefresh={onRefreshSpy} />);

    expect(onRefreshSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(60000);
    expect(onRefreshSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(60000);
    expect(onRefreshSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```